# How do you create a dns server for wildcard domains on localhost for use with node/express?

Tags: node.js, express, dns

I would like to create a local https server using express that handles any subdomain of example.com.  Ideally I would like to modify my hosts file like this:
127.0.0.2 localhost *.example.com
but this is not allowed.
So I would like to create my own dns server to resolve the IP for *.example.com to 127.0.0.2.  I have looked at https://github.com/tjfontaine/node-dns and https://github.com/iriscouch/dnsd but I don't understand how to apply them to my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

[xip.io](http://xip.io/) may not work for you, but I've found it to be extremely useful. "xip.io is a magic domain name that provides wildcard DNS for any IP address." "xip.io runs a custom DNS server on the public Internet. When your computer looks up a xip.io domain, the xip.io DNS server extracts the IP address from the domain and sends it back in the response."

So all of the following domains will resolve to 127.0.0.1:

```
127.0.0.1.xip.io
www.127.0.0.1.xip.io
example.com.127.0.0.1.xip.io
something.example.com.127.0.0.1.xip.io
```

([The daemon](https://github.com/sstephenson/xipd) happens to be written in Coffeescript to run on node.js.)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run a local DNS server to intercept the requests.

I have found [`dnsproxy.py`](http://code.google.com/p/marlon-tools/source/browse/tools/dnsproxy/dnsproxy.py) to work quite well. It is written in python and needs to be running while you intend on using it.

You will need to edit your `hosts` file and add a line like this:

```
127.0.0.1    *.example.com
```

After that you will need to start the DNS proxy server:

```
$ sudo python dnsproxy.py -s 8.8.8.8
```

`8.8.8.8` is the IP address of Google's DNS servers that will be used as a fallback if the record is not found in the hosts file.

Once you have done this, you should be able to start an express server on port `80` and handle requests to `*.example.com`.

Comment: This needs to work cross-platform.  You cannot use wildcards in the hosts file under Windows.

Comment: The same process works on Windows. No OS supports wildcards in the hosts file, the python script reads the wildcards from the hosts file and enforces them.

Comment: I still don't see dns requests going through the local script.  When I start my node server I still get `Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1020:19)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at net.js:1135:9
    at asyncCallback (dns.js:68:16)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:121:9)`

Answer (score 1):

There were some things that were tripping me up that I have worked through.

1. I wasn't setting up the DNS server IP address in the Network setting of my machine.
2. I had a timing issue between starting the DNS server and starting the https server.
3. I wasn't including a port number in the DNS response

Here is my solution:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var dns = require('native-dns');
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');

String.prototype.endsWith = function(s) {
  return this.length >= s.length && this.substr(this.length - s.length) == s;
};

var startDns = function(example_port, callback) {
  var server = dns.createServer();

  server.on('request', function(request, response) {
    var found = false;

    for (var q = 0; q < request.question.length; q++)
    {
      var name = request.question[q].name;
      if (name.endsWith("example.com"))
      {
        response.answer.push(dns.A({
          name:name,
          address:'127.0.0.2',
          port:example_port,
          ttl:600
        }));
        found = true;
      }
    }
    if (found)
    {
      response.send();
    }
  });

  server.on('error', function(err, buff, req, res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
  });

  server.on('listening', function() {
    console.log("DNS server started on port 53");
    if (callback)
    {
      callback();
    }
  });

   server.serve(53);
   return server;
};

var startHttps = function(serverPort) {
  // Set up secure server
  var options = {
    key:fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'certificates/example.com-key.pem')),
    cert:fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'certificates/example.com-cert.pem'))
  };

  var app = express();
  var server = https.createServer(options, app);
  app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('Hello from ' + req.headers.host);
  });
  server.listen(serverPort, 'example.com');
  console.log('https server started on port ' + serverPort);
  return server;
};

var server_port = parseInt(process.argv[2] || 8082);
var httpsServer;

var dnsServer = startDns(server_port, function() {
  httpsServer = startHttps(server_port)
});

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  console.log("shutting down");
  if (httpsServer)
  {
    httpsServer.close();
  }
  if (dnsServer)
  {
    dnsServer.close();
  }
});
```

Notes: This is working on my Windows machine.  I am still testing on other platforms.  I am not sure if I am correctly handling domains in my dns server that aren't recognized.

Comment: This does not work on OSX. The error I get is `Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL at errnoException (net.js:900:11) at Server._listen2 (net.js:1019:19) at listen (net.js:1060:10) at net.js:1134:9 at asyncCallback (dns.js:68:16) at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:121:9)`